# Inverse Propagation of Uncertainty

Tags: reference-request, error-propagation

Can any one help me find a reference under the title of  " Inverse Propagation of Uncertainty". I am starting a research on this topic after I had studied the forward propagation of uncertainty.

Thank you in advance

Comment: That's interesting. What is the meaning of inverse propagation of uncertainty? I thought that the underlying filtration imposes a forward flow of information.

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis  In general, a forward propagation of uncertainty  studies  the influence of the uncertainty in the inputs of a model  on the  output. For the inverse(or backward) one search for methods that help do the reverse, i.e. given the uncertainty  of the output, how one would predict the uncertainty of the input ( it is some kind of generalisation of parameter estimation error analysis).

Answer (score 2):

Chapter 5 of Hartley & Zisserman, *Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision* treats the topic.